# setOpaque is true, but JPanel won't change the background color

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel

I'm making a restaurant menu program with GUI.

I created 3 JPanels and set Background(Color.white) to one of them.

But java will not display that background color.

What's wrong?

Here is my code

please do not take any attention to foods' price and cardLayout. Not finished with coding.

```
public class MainDishPanel extends JPanel {

JCheckBox box1 = new JCheckBox("Hamburger 5 dollars"),
          box2 = new JCheckBox("Pizza 5 dollars"),
          box3 = new JCheckBox("French Hot dog 5 dollars");
MainDishPanel(){
   setOpaque(true);
   setBackground(Color.white);
   setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
  // setBorder();

  add(box1);add(box2);add(box3);
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

class with main method:

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class RestaurantMenu extends JFrame implements ActionListener{



/* private JPanel maindishPanel= new JPanel(),
                   dessertPanel = new JPanel(),
                   drinkPanel = new JPanel(),*/
    private JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(),
                   rightPanel = new JPanel();
    private MainDishPanel maindish = new MainDishPanel();
    private DessertPanel dessert = new DessertPanel();
    private DrinkPanel drink = new DrinkPanel();
    private LinkedList<Double>price = new LinkedList<>();
    private JButton left = new JButton("previous"),
                    right = new JButton("next");
    public int page =1;
     private JLabel pageLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(page)),
                    foodTypeLabel = new JLabel();
     CardLayout cards;
     GridBagLayout grid;
    RestaurantMenu(){
        setTitle("Main Dish");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        add(foodTypeLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(pageLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(maindish, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        grid = new GridBagLayout();
        leftPanel.setLayout(grid); leftPanel.add(left);
        rightPanel.setLayout(grid); rightPanel.add(right);
        right.addActionListener(this);
        left.addActionListener(this);
        //cards = new CardLayout();
        /*cards = (CardLayout)maindishPanel.getLayout();
        cards.show(maindishPanel,"Main Dish");*/
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500,500);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==right)
            cards.next(this);
        if(e.getSource()==left)
            cards.previous(this);
    }
    public static void main (String []args){
        RestaurantMenu rm = new RestaurantMenu();

    }
}
```

I don't get any error. Background color just won't be changed to white.

RestaurantMenu class can be looked like a spaghetti code or something strange

because I have plenty things to do  with that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your MainDishPanel you need to set the background color for the JCheckBox to white, or you can just setOpaque to false on your JCheckBox

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainDishPanel extends JPanel {

    JCheckBox box1 = new JCheckBox("Hamburger 5 dollars"), box2 = new JCheckBox("Pizza 5 dollars"),
        box3 = new JCheckBox("French Hot dog 5 dollars");

    MainDishPanel() {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        box1.setBackground(Color.WHITE); // or box1.setOpaque(false);
        box2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        box3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        add(box1);
        add(box2);
        add(box3);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, could you mark it as answer if I solved your problem :)

Comment: Yes! Did it! :)